# How to make a List Item Read Only in Quick Edit Mode? SP2013/SP2016 on premise

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, quick-edit

I want to make a list item read only for a certain group when one of it's column has a value of "Completed".

I want to achieve it through jquery and server side code.

Comment: You need to break the item level permission for that group and assign it to Read-only when a column value is "Completed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following JSLink to the list view will make the Completed field read-only while in Quick Edit mode.

```
(function () {
    var overrideContext = {};
    overrideContext.Templates = overrideContext.Templates || {};

    overrideContext.Templates.OnPreRender = function (ctx) {
        disableGridEditing("Completed");
    }

    function disableGridEditing(fieldName) {
        var fields = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function (f) {
            return f.Name === fieldName;
        });
        if (fields.length > 0) {
            fields[0].AllowGridEditing = false;
        }
    }

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
})();
```